# Issue with Room Database Flow and ViewModel in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, kotlin-flow

I'm encountering a problem with fetching a list from Room using Flow in my Android `ViewModel`. I'm trying to use the list inside the `ViewModel` with an index, but it seems that the list is empty or not updating as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my `ViewModel` setup:

```kotlin
// Code for your ViewModel
class YourViewModel(private val usersRepository: UsersRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _users = usersRepository.getAllUsers().shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 1)
    val users: StateFlow<List<User>> = _users.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

    // Index to keep track of the current position in the list of users
    private var currentIndex = MutableStateFlow(0)

    // Function to get the current user based on the currentIndex
    fun getCurrentUser(): User? {
        val currentList = users.value
        return if (currentIndex.value in currentList.indices) {
            currentList[currentIndex.value]
        } else {
            null // Return null if the index is out of bounds
        }
    }

    // Function to handle button click and update the currentIndex
    fun onButtonClick() {
        currentIndex.value = (currentIndex.value + 1) % users.value.size
    }
}
```

I've verified that `getAllUsers()` in `usersRepository` fetches data from the Room database, but when I try to use the users `StateFlow` with an index in my `ViewModel`, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how I can debug it effectively? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re mixing flows (reactive code) with non-suspending imperative code, which doesn’t really make sense. Since you’re users are coming from a flow, instead of requesting a current user with an imperative function that might get called too early, you should be doing your tasks in a flow collector.